# Xorg hanged after fresh install ( Debian buster [AMD/ATI] Picasso (rev c1) )

Tags: debian, amd-graphics, ati

Just installed Debian buster and Xfce. After booting, Xorg is hanged, screen black and cursor blinking eternally.

I really appreciate a hand, because I have missed something or did something wrong.

My current kernel version and graphic card

```
Linux 4.19.0-12-amd64 x86_64 Debian
04:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Picasso (rev c1)
```

I have followed this steps:

Fresh Debian buster netinst without any x11 enviroment. Just console mode.

Graphic card and model

`04:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Picasso (rev c1)`

Updated the repositories adding `non-free contrib` and installed the packages:

```
firmware-linux-nonfree firmware-realtek firmware-amd-graphics libgl1-mesa-dri libglx-mesa0 mesa-vulkan-drivers xserver-xorg-video-all
```

Also copied the file `picasso_ta.bin`  to `/usr/lib/firmware/amdgpu/` like [here](https://blog.hartwork.org/posts/how-to-get-debian-wifiwlan-and-amd-graphics-running-on-lenovo-thinkpad-e495/)

Executed `tasksel` and selected xfce.

Tried a new xorg.conf running

```bsh
Xorg -configure
X -config /root/xorg.conf.new
```

Current logs

#### Short Xorg.0.log

```
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[     4.710] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[     4.710] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[     4.710] (EE) Device(s) detected, but none match those in the config file.
[     4.710] (EE)
[     4.710] (EE) no screens found(EE)
[     4.710] (EE)
[     4.710] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
[     4.710] (EE)
[     4.711] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

#### Xorg.0.log

```
[     4.701]
X.Org X Server 1.20.4
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[     4.701] Build Operating System: Linux 4.19.0-12-amd64 x86_64 Debian
[     4.701] Current Operating System: Linux opos 4.19.0-14-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.171-2 (2021-01-30) x86_64
[     4.701] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.19.0-14-amd64 root=UUID=712affb5-f108-43a7-bbf8-48a9ca023656 ro quiet
[     4.702] Build Date: 01 December 2020  05:59:57PM
[     4.702] xorg-server 2:1.20.4-1+deb10u2 (https://www.debian.org/support)
[     4.702] Current version of pixman: 0.36.0
[     4.702]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
        to make sure that you have the latest version.
[     4.702] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
        (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[     4.702] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Mon Mar  8 18:51:11 2021
[     4.702] (==) Using config file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf"
[     4.702] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[     4.702] (==) ServerLayout "X.org Configured"
[     4.702] (**) |-->Screen "Screen0" (0)
[     4.702] (**) |   |-->Monitor "Monitor0"
[     4.703] (**) |   |-->Device "Card0"
[     4.703] (**) |-->Screen "Screen1" (1)
[     4.703] (**) |   |-->Monitor "Monitor1"
[     4.703] (**) |   |-->Device "Card1"
[     4.703] (**) |-->Input Device "Mouse0"
[     4.703] (**) |-->Input Device "Keyboard0"
[     4.703] (==) Automatically adding devices
[     4.703] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[     4.703] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[     4.703] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff
[     4.703] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[     4.703]    Entry deleted from font path.
[     4.703] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[     4.703]    Entry deleted from font path.
[     4.703] (**) FontPath set to:
        /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
        /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled,
        /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/:unscaled,
        /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
        /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi,
        /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi,
        built-ins,
        /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
        /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled,
        /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/:unscaled,
        /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
        /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi,
        /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi,
        built-ins
[     4.703] (**) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[     4.703] (WW) Hotplugging is on, devices using drivers 'kbd', 'mouse' or 'vmmouse' will be disabled.
[     4.703] (WW) Disabling Mouse0
[     4.703] (WW) Disabling Keyboard0
[     4.703] (II) Loader magic: 0x55bee4dbce20
[     4.703] (II) Module ABI versions:
[     4.703]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[     4.703]    X.Org Video Driver: 24.0
[     4.703]    X.Org XInput driver : 24.1
[     4.703]    X.Org Server Extension : 10.0
[     4.704] (++) using VT number 7

[     4.704] (II) systemd-logind: logind integration requires -keeptty and -keeptty was not provided, disabling logind integration
[     4.707] (--) PCI:*(4@0:0:0) 1002:15d8:1043:12f2 rev 193, Mem @ 0xe0000000/268435456, 0xf0000000/2097152, 0xfcc00000/524288, I/O @ 0x0000e000/256
[     4.708] (II) "glx" will be loaded. This was enabled by default and also specified in the config file.
[     4.708] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[     4.708] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[     4.709] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     4.709]    compiled for 1.20.4, module version = 1.0.0
[     4.709]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 10.0
[     4.709] (II) LoadModule: "amdgpu"
[     4.709] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/amdgpu_drv.so
[     4.709] (II) Module amdgpu: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     4.709]    compiled for 1.20.3, module version = 18.1.99
[     4.709]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[     4.709]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.0
[     4.709] (II) AMDGPU: Driver for AMD Radeon:
        All GPUs supported by the amdgpu kernel driver
[     4.710] (II) AMDGPU(0): [KMS] drm report modesetting isn't supported.
[     4.710] (II) AMDGPU(1): [KMS] drm report modesetting isn't supported.
[     4.710] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[     4.710] (II) UnloadModule: "amdgpu"
[     4.710] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[     4.710] (II) UnloadModule: "amdgpu"
[     4.710] (EE) Device(s) detected, but none match those in the config file.
[     4.710] (EE)
Fatal server error:
[     4.710] (EE) no screens found(EE)
[     4.710] (EE)
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support
         at http://wiki.x.org
 for help.
[     4.710] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
[     4.710] (EE)
[     4.711] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally solved the issue installing a backport kernel and firmware

- Enable backports repo

```bsh
echo deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports main contrib non-free \
| sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/buster-backports.list
sudo apt update
```

- Install backported kernel ( without break anything)

```bsh
sudo apt install -t buster-backports linux-image-amd64
```

- Install ati firmware

```bsh
sudo apt install -t buster-backports firmware-linux firmware-linux-nonfree
```

Reboot